# Using Django with Eclipse - making sure Django is installed correctly

Tags: python, django, eclipse, directory, installation

all.

Note that I'm a newbie to Django and Python. I keep feeling like I'm missing very small details, and they're probably related to Eclipse's GUI.

Python is installed here:

```
C:\Python32
```

...and Django is installed here:

```
C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\django
```

Note that I ran python from a command prompt to check my Version of Django. It worked. I'm running version 1.5.

Problems come when I try to create a new Django project using Eclipse. This is what happens:

- I'll specify that I want to create a new Django project
- I'll select my interpreter, give my project a name, and select a grammar version (3.0)
- "Add Project Directory to PYTHONPATH" is selected

When I click "Next" I get an error message saying that "Django wasn't found".

But when Python is run from a command prompt (and I "import Django"), Python seems to know where Django is. Python doesn't seem know where Django is when I try to create a Django project in Eclipse.

I feel like I'm missing something very, very small - an environment variable or something. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the python interpreter to 3.2? if there are a 2.x installation, python tends to point to that by default

Comment: Also consider pycharm which has django project templates and other goodies: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: Karthikr - Yes. It's here: C:\Python32\python.exe

What else might I be missing?

Comment: Dide you try the command line instruction `django-admin.py startproject mysite` to create your project?

Comment: I think @karthikr means is python32 in your system path for windows?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added the Django install path to the system `PYTHONPATH` list. For PyDev in Eclipse, the python path can be found under "Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter - Python"

Click on the `New Folder` button, navigate to the Django install path (it will be found at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django` if you installed it to the default directory), and click `OK`

Comment: or : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django